# Jquery javascript html label modify value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide a field and show it and also change the value of a variable depending on a `checkbox` value using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CompanyName').hide();    
    $('#inlineCheckbox1').click(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
       if ($this.is(':checked')) {
          $('#CompanyName').show();
          $("label[for='AdresseName']").text('Adresse Name');
       } else {
          $('#CompanyName').hide();
          $("label[for='AdresseName']").text('Name');
       }
   });
});
```

it shows and hides the `textfield` fine, but the `label` text change does not work for me... it's like if the `label` change line of code is not being executed. What's going on? My HTML is this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="isCompany" class="col-sm-2 control-label">It's a company</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="CompanyName">
        <label for="companyName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="AdresseName" class="col-sm-2 control-label" id="AdresseNameNotCompnay">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AdresseName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
  </div>    
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LucasTrz/MLkT7/

Comment: Why not use $("#AdresseNameNotCompnay") ?

Comment: Thank you  @Lucas Trzesniewski... then it should be my browser... let me check again!

Comment: Aside: You should bind to **change** on a checkbox, not click - there is more than one way to change it. And that label should wrap the checkbox or at least use `for` to trigger it - users expect the checkbox to toggle when they click its text.